# Philips 288E2 DDC/CI does not work. Connected to Intel UHD Graphics 750 via DisplayPort (or HDMI) on Windows 11,

Tags: display, intel-graphics, brightness, plug-and-play

I am trying to control brightness on my `Philips 288E2`. Monitor connected to Windows 11 using a Intel UHD Graphics 750 via DisplayPort or HDMI. (I've tried both)

I've tried various desktop programs, scripts, all report error. For example `Monitorian` say

> PHL 288E2 Monitor is not controllable. DDC/CI is not supported or
> enabled

The monitor spec states in user manual:

> Plug & Play Compatibility: DDC/CI, Mac OSX, sRGB, Windows 10/8.1/8/7

See: [official user manual](https://www.download.p4c.philips.com/files/2/288e2a_75/288e2a_75_dfu_eng.pdf)

There is no such setting in monitor menu Enable/Disable DDC/CI, neither user manual mentions it.

**Edit:** I've downloaded official drivers and Philips official SmartControl. It displays the similar menu as the monitor's native menu but all menu items are disabled (including Picture/Brightness, etc, except Setup/Information. which btw shows **DDCCI: NO**. In the native onscreen Setup/Information **there is no such data**, a way fewer parameter is displayed

**Question**

What am I missing, and how can I configure my system OS? Monitor? to enable DDC/CI, so I can use programs to control brightness?

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Which drivers are you using?

Comment: Intel Corporation, 2021. 01. 04. 27.20.100.9127, which installed by Windows 11 (and updates) Btw, Intel Graphics Command Center reports "DDC2 Protocol Supported"

Comment: And no drivers for the monitor itself??

Comment: Many thx, good point. Now I installed the official driver, downloaded from Philips. Nothing changed, except Windows Device Manager now displays Philips 288E2 Monitor instead Generic PNP Monitor. I also downloaded official Philips SmartControl, it displays the similar menu as the monitor's native menu but all menu items are disabled except Setup/Information. which btw shows **DDCCI: NO. ** In the native onscreen Setup/Information there is no such data, a way fewer parameter is displayed

Comment: From a remark in the [manual](https://gzhls.at/blob/ldb/4/4/0/5/bd6a44e167e16ba2f2291ee6a299a883295d.pdf) : "enter to the OSD to set DPS to OFF mode". Also, according to the manual, this monitor has automatic brightness control with "SmartImage" and "SmartContrast". Try to see if you can disable all smart options.

Comment: @harrymc, many thx. DPS is missing in my Picture menu, btw Over Scan too. Smart functions are based on image content, and way not smart, a) they burn out my retina, b) very annoying as they continuously slow/delayed changing the picture while its contents changes. My use case is change the brightness according to room light, night day, I am OK to do it manually, but want via Desktop and not OSD so DDC is the way. Now I am pretty disappointed about the contradiction between product specification and its provided actual capabilities, and I want to see clear what is going on, see bounty remarks

Comment: You might need to get a dumber monitor model...

Answer (score 0):

My own conclusion is the the
[Philips 288E2](https://www.usa.philips.com/c-p/288E2E_27/4k-ultra-hd-lcd-monitor)
is undoubtedly a very good monitor, but it just does not do what you require.

The description of the terminal and its
[manual](https://gzhls.at/blob/ldb/4/4/0/5/bd6a44e167e16ba2f2291ee6a299a883295d.pdf)
contain lots of references to its in-built smart technology that will
automatically adapt the picture as regarding brightness, contrast,
game mode etc. There is no mention of any PC control and especially
DDCCI is showing "NO".

My conclusion is that Philips were too confident of the smartness
that they built into the 288E2, so confident that they forgot about
program control. They allowed setting parameters by the OSD,
and were very confident of being able to follow them automatically
in all cases and situations.

My advice is to return this monitor and get another that
really supports DDCCI. It's better to verify important details
in the publicity against independent reviews and user cases,
because the publicity materials were not written by engineers.

Comment: Many thx for your thoughts. I think smart functions are completely out of topic regarding DDC is working or not, (which is the OP about) regardless they are good or not. Besides of going out of topic and talking about automatic picture adopt function instead of programmability of (all) functions, how can the a picture adopting function so smart, knowing the room ambient light *without* a light sensor? I would add that *you need a dumber monitor* is a bit misleading, when the use case is that I need a monitor which supports DDC and/or have light sensor and my monitor seems to lack of both...

Comment: In your answer the statement "manual...There is no mention of any PC control" is explicitly false, please see the screenshot from manual in my post, or the original manual link. It explicitly states DDC and Mac OSX Windows. The DDCCI: NO screenshot is from the actual Philips diagnostics program and the issue itself.

Comment: The description wasn't written by a technical guy. I usually verify what's written against other reviews and user cases on the internet, because the publicity can be wrong. Or your firmware is defective. In both cases my advice to return it stands. And by "dumber" I mean a monitor that listens to the user, meaning  DDCCI, and doesn't think it's capable of doing everything perfectly and automatically according to the OSD parameters.